# Printing multiple iterations of the same report

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to emulate the behavior of the **Print Statements** page (AR503500) where according to the Customers selected, their corresponding Customer Statement report (AR641500) is printed out in one sequential Report/PDF.

Reviewing the logic from graph **ARStatementPrint.cs** I can see this being handled in the **PrintStatements** delegate where an iteration over the *DetailsResult* list is printing the report

The key seems to be the **CombineReport** method which is executed within the iteration:

```
        foreach (DetailsResult t in list)
        {
            if (markOnly)
            {
                if (filter.ShowAll != true)
                    foreach (ARStatement doc in docview.SelectMulti(filter.StatementCycleId, filter.StatementDate, t.CustomerID, t.CuryID))
                    {
                        if (arsetup?.ConsolidatedStatement != true && doc.BranchID != filter.BranchID)
                            continue;

                        doc.DontPrint = true;
                        docview.Cache.Update(doc);
                    }
            }
            else
            {

                Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                d[ARStatementReportParams.Parameters.BranchID] = filter.BranchCD;                   
                d[ARStatementReportParams.Fields.StatementCycleID] = filter.StatementCycleId;
                d[ARStatementReportParams.Fields.StatementDate]    = filter.StatementDate.Value.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                d[ARStatementReportParams.Fields.CustomerID] = t.CustomerID.ToString();

                if (filter.ShowAll == true)
                {
                    d[ARStatementReportParams.Parameters.IgnorePrintFlags] = ARStatementReportParams.BoolValues.True;
                }
                else
                {
                    d[ARStatementReportParams.Fields.PrintStatements] = ARStatementReportParams.BoolValues.True;
                }
                if (filter.CuryStatements ?? false)
                    d[ARStatementReportParams.Fields.CuryID] = t.CuryID;

                foreach (ARStatement doc in docview.SelectMulti(filter.StatementCycleId, filter.StatementDate, t.CustomerID, t.CuryID))
                {
                    if (arsetup?.ConsolidatedStatement != true && doc.BranchID != filter.BranchID)
                        continue;

                    if (doc.Printed != true)
                    {
                        doc.Printed = true;
                        docview.Cache.Update(doc);
                    }
                }

                ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex,  GetCustomerReportID(graph, reportID, t), d);
            }
        }

        graph.Actions.PressSave();
        if(ex != null) throw ex;
```

In my own graph, I created a first action where no iteration takes place and a single report print request is made

```
protected virtual IEnumerable AnotherReport(PXAdapter adapter)
    {

            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters["CustomerID"] = "001208";

            parameters["BranchID"] = "BRANCH1";
            parameters["DateFrom"] = "01-01-2017";
            parameters["DateTo"] = "12-12-2017";


            throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "TR101000", "ReportTest");                
    }
```

In this case the result is correct. Then I implemented the CombineReport method in the following way

```
        protected virtual IEnumerable Report(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        PXReportRequiredException ex = null;
        foreach (Customer doc in adapter.Get<Customer>())
        {
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters["CustomerID"] = doc.AcctCD;

            parameters["BranchID"] = "BRANCH1";
            parameters["DateFrom"] = "01-01-2017";
            parameters["DateTo"] = "12-12-2017";

            ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex,  "TR101000", parameters);
        }

        this.Save.Press();
        if (ex != null) throw ex;

        return adapter.Get();
    }
```

But the result only prints the information from one customer.

The **ARPrintInvoices** graph was also used as a reference but the information available in the **ardocumentlist** delegate and the **GetBQLStatement** method doesn't seem to print any reports nor use the CombineReport method.

Any suggestions as to how to address this?
Thanks!

Comment: MergeLast param on the CombineReport method defaults to true if is not specified. Try passing 'false' on the last iteration. (example: "ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex,  "TR101000", parameters, !isLastIteration);")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MergeLast param on the CombineReport method defaults to true if is not specified. Try passing 'false' on the last iteration.

```
ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex, "TR101000", parameters, !isLastIteration);
```

See Snippet below:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
  public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    public PXAction<PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoice> Test;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test")]
    protected void test()
    {
       PXReportRequiredException ex = null;
        var row = Base.Document.Current;

        if(row.RefNbr != null)
        {
          Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
          dictionary["DocType"] = row.DocType;
          dictionary["RefNbr"] = row.RefNbr;

          ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex,  "AR610500", dictionary);
        }
        if (row.RefNbr != null)
        {

          Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
          dictionary["DocType"] = row.DocType;
          dictionary["RefNbr"] = row.RefNbr;

          ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex, "AR610500", dictionary,false);
        }

        if (ex != null)
        {
          ex.Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New;
          ex.SeparateWindows = false;
          throw ex;
        }
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```